# Implementing a game engine specific programming language

Tags: compiler-construction, cross-platform, game-engine

Sorry for any spelling mistakes or basic grammar faults, i was never good at English at school... And of course thanks in advance.

My goal is to make a game engine and editor that is easy to use for its users, but can still be used to develop quality 3d games.

To facilitate the users i'd like to implement a custom programming language for designing the game logic, AI behavior, weapon systems and so on.
But restricting them from the low level aspects of the engine.

Eventually i would like to make the game engine able to support multiple platforms, but as i don't have the money to buy the platforms i'd like to include, this can not be implemented now...

My first notion was to build a scripting language, but i'm very worried about the system overhead of not running the user code native. Because i would also like the user to be for example able to edit mesh vertices, creating a custom path-finding system, or other more computation intensive tasks.

So i assumed compiling the user code to binary was the best option. And this is where many questions start to pop up.

I prefer to be aware of what is going on in the generated executable, and have full control of the result. And so i am not very fond to use existing tools such as llvm to generate the executable in fear of losing control.
And i would like to learn more about how code is ran on the cpu at a lower level and memory management and so on...
But mostly because i just like to do as much as i can myself.

The problems i'm running in to are:
- Considering the above is generating binary code really the best option? (or should i stick with a scripting language)

- Currently i'm writing a program for generating a windows exe file and inserting opcodes. is this okay, or should i instead use existing tools as llvm?
- Are there any legal actions, licenses or such i need to be aware of before generating custom windows exe files?
- As one of my goals is to later deploy the engine to multiple platforms, is hand writing a custom program for translating the user code to the specific platform instruction set any similar to the x86 instruction set. or will it be a lot harder?

I hope that i explained the problem in enough detail. if anyone has any questions feel free to post, and i'll explain myself.

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: Have a look at LPC, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPC_%28programming_language%29 and its integration with LPmud

Answer (score -2):

First of all u should really reconsider it idea. If u really want your game engine to be used by people in both aspects for generating games and afterwards modding an existing game, u will have to stick to already established standards. The reason for this is simple - modders are mostly beginners in programming, had hard times learning Lua, Boo,... They really do not have time and afford to switch to ur custom language. So for scripting u really should stick to industry standards.

On the other hand u really have to separate in ur design between a mod and an content extension that doesn't need low level access or had high cpu usage.

Considering all these facts, I highly recommend the following :

- establish a mod system for the engine (based on a well known language like c# or java script)
- establish a scripting interface to control the behavior of it entities / components.

That's the common way. If u move away of such a established standard, u will probably have some serious trouble.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't mean for the engine to have a mod system, sorry it was written very unclear, so i edited that part in the post.
I would really appreciate if u could take a look at it again. Thanks

Comment: Sr but even it is forr the editor, or the game itself, the concept is allways the same as above described. Stick to defaults, and sepperrate between mod/script when low level access is needed. That's all